# reading lines and handling the data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code for reading multiple lines of a text file into arrays, then changing the str values to int, then printing the int.
Could anyone help with suggesting a more eloquent way of doing this ?

the text file values are lines of 4 numbers separated by a space character.

eg

```
1 2 3 4
3 6 8 5
3 8 1 7 
3 6 7 8 
3 5 6 8
```

```
    with open('file2.txt') as f:
        data = [f.readline().rstrip().split(' ') for x in range(4)]

    # print(data)

    array1, array2, array3, array4 = data

    count = 1

    for i in array1:
val = int(i)
# print(val)

if count == 1:
    val1 = val
elif count == 2:
    val2 = val
elif count == 3:
    val3 = val
elif count == 4:
    val4 = val
count += 1

    count = 1

    for i in array2:
        val = int(i)
        # print(val)

        if count == 1:
            val5 = val
        elif count == 2:
            val6 = val
        elif count == 3:
            val7 = val
        elif count == 4:
            val8 = val
        count += 1

    for i in array3:
val = int(i)
# print(val)

if count == 1:
    val9 = val
elif count == 2:
    val10 = val
elif count == 3:
    val11 = val
elif count == 4:
    val12 = val
count += 1

    for i in array4:
val = int(i)
# print(val)

if count == 1:
    val13 = val
elif count == 2:
    val14 = val
elif count == 3:
    val15 = val
elif count == 4:
    val16 = val
count += 1

    print(val1, val2, val3, val4)
    print(val5, val6, val7, val8)
    print(val9,val10,val11,val12)
    print(val13,val14,val15,val16)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. You need to provide a [mre]. The main problem is that your code isn't properly indented, but also you're missing the output.

Comment: Also, can you show your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with your way of reading the file, you could use something like this:

```
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    data = [f.readline().rstrip().split(' ') for x in range(5)]

data = [[int(x) for x in i] for i in data]

for each in data:
  print(*each)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
3 6 8 5
3 8 1 7
3 6 7 8
3 5 6 8
```

Or:

```
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    data = [f.readline().rstrip().split(' ') for x in range(5)]

for each in list(map(int,i) for i in data):
  print(*each)
```

Comment: thankyou wjandrea.
the thing is, I have to store each line in a list to process further

Comment: This another andrei/andrea, but that's ok :) `data = [[int(x) for x in i] for i in data]` stores each line in a sublist of the data like this: `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 6, 8, 5], [3, 8, 1, 7], [3, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 8]]`